# How to show that lattice of subgroups D4 isn't modular lattice?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, lattice-orders

Here is a lattice of subgroups D4.
[image]

*The lattice isn't modular iff there is a "pentagon" as a sublattice.*

As we can see $\left \{ \rho_{0} \right\} - \left \{ \rho_{0}, \mu_1 \right\} - \left \{ \rho_{0}, \rho_{2},\mu_1, \mu_2 \right\} - D_4 - \left \{ p_{0}, \delta _2 \right\} - \left \{ p_{0} \right\}$ is a pentagon. Is it enough?

I also know the Modular law, here we have: Let $a = \left \{ \rho_{0}, \mu_1 \right\} , b = \left \{ \rho_{0}, \rho_{2},\mu_1, \mu_2 \right\}, x = \left \{ \rho_{0}, \delta_{2} \right\}$, than $a ∨ (x ∧ b) = \left \{ \rho_{0}, \mu_1 \right\} ∨ (\left \{ \rho_{0}, \delta_{2} \right\} ∧ \left \{ \rho_{0}, \rho_{2},\mu_1, \mu_2 \right\}) =\left \{ \rho_{0}, \mu_1 \right\} ∨ \left \{ \rho_{0}, \delta_{2} \right\}$

And I don't understand what will be a supremum of this, how does the operations ∨ and ∧ work in this case? Thank you for any clarifications.

Comment: That is not a pentagon because $\{\rho_0,\rho_2\}\leq\{\rho_0,\rho_2,\mu_1,\mu_2\}$, but replace $\{\rho_0,\rho_2\}$ with $\{\rho_0,\delta_2\}$ and you have it.

Comment: By the way, $\rho$ is rendered as `\rho`, it's not $p$.

Comment: @amrsa, thank you very much, and what about my last question about operations?

Comment: The supremum is, as always, the least upper bound. Check the common upper bounds of generic elements $x$ and $y$, and pick the least one. Dually for the infimum, or greatest lower bound.